# Soluions over ring of integers from an non archimedean field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, local-field, nonarchimedian-analysis

This is [Proposition 1.9](https://kskedlaya.org/papers/perfectoids-icts-bib.pdf).  I am confused with the forward direction:

If $K$ is alg. closed narc field with $x$ a nonzero element with posiive norm. Then:

1. $K$ is not discrete.
2. Every polynomial over $O_K/(x)$ has a root in $O_K/(x)$.

where $O_K$ is ring of inegers of $K$.

---

My problems/ thoughts. Suppose I have a polynomial over $O_K/(x)$ of form
$\sum a_i t^i$ when lifted to $K$. It has root $y \in K$. But I don't see how we can scale $y$ so as to obtain new root in $O_K/(x)$.

any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The valuation/norm on $K$ is not discrete because $v(x^{n/m}) = v(x) n/m$.

Every **monic** polynomial $\in O_K[t]$ has a root in $O_K$.

$pt-1\in O_{\overline{Q}_p}/(p^2)[t]$ doesn't have a root in $O_{\overline{Q}_p}/(p^2)$.

Comment: Sorry, why is it true that every monic has a root?

Comment: Because it has a root in $K$ and its valuation can't be negative

Comment: I see if $p(t) = \sum_0^n a_i t^i$, with $a_i \in O, a_n=1$, then if exist $y \in K$,  $|p(y)|=0 \Rightarrow |y|\le 1$ for otherwise, $|p(y)|>0$. But this means that every monic polynoomial factors in $O[t]$ by induction?